# The product of $(a_1-1)(a_2-2)....(a_{169}- 169)$ is

Tags: permutations

Let $a_1,a_2,.....a_{169} $ represent any arbitrary permutation of the number $1,2,3....169$. Then the product $(a_1-1)(a_2-2)......(a_{169} - 169)$ is

1. Odd only for some permutation, not all
2. Always even, whatever be the permutation
3. Always odd, whatever be the permutation
4. Even only for some permutation, not all

I have no idea how to solve this problem .

Comment: Is "even" a possible choice?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes

Comment: Is "an integer" a possible choice?  Is "difficult and I don't want to do it" a possible choice?  Obviously (1-1)(2-2)....(169 - 169) = 0 but (2-1)....(169-168)(169-1) $\ne$ 0$ so there is not single answer so ... what are we expected to answer?  Everything we can?  Anything that's true?  Anything that's definite?  Nothing that is indefinite?

Comment: @fleablood I have added the choices

Comment: Hagen van Eitzens answer is pretty good.  If so much as one single $a_i - i$ is even then the product is even.  To be odd *every* single $a_i - i$ must be odd. Obviously some $a_i-i$ can be even.  So the question boils down to: is it possible to make a permutation where all the $a_i - i$ are odd.  As there are more odd $i$ and $a_i$ then even there must be at least one $a_i$ and $i$ both odd.  I find it odd that there is no option 5) more than one are even and more than one are odd.  If 1 and 4 were supposed to be "permutation*s*" than 1 and 4 are equivalent.

Comment: So, does it have to be positive, negative, non-positive, non-negative?

Comment: What's the difference between option 1 and option 4? Hint: When is the product of two integers odd?

Answer (score 2):

There are more odd than even indices, hence some $a_{\text{odd}}$ must be odd, thus making the product even.